# Comment reformuler le texte cité dans le corps de la question de manière à le rendre plus clair et élégant?

Tags: reformulation

"Lorsque tu atteins ou dépasses le seuil de 40 heures de travail cumulé entre tes deux fonctions dans la compagnie, est-ce que ton taux de rémunération est majoré? Les heures de chaque fonction sont-elles combinées ou sont-elles traitées de manière distincte?"

Serait-il préférable d’écrire « cumulé pour tes deux fonctions »?

"Lorsque tu atteins ou dépasses le seuil de 40 heures de travail cumulé pour tes deux fonctions dans la compagnie, est-ce que ton taux de rémunération est majoré? Les heures de chaque fonction sont-elles combinées ou sont-elles traitées séparément?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Entre » semble être une possibilité dans  certains contextes, mais je n'en suis pas sûr et je ne trouve rien qui soit une confirmation. « Pour » est souvent utilisé après « cumulé », mais pour indiquer un récipient, un complément circonstanciel de temps, de but, ou autre, ou un agent (rare); cela peut être vérifié sur cette page : ([cumulé pour](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cumul%C3%A9%20pour%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)). « Pour » n'est pas une préposition très spécifique.

Il me semble qu'une préposition vraiment appropriée ne pourrait être qu'un terme comme « *relativement à* ».

> (TLFi) **A. − Relativement à**
>
> **1.** Pour ce qui est de, en ce qui concerne. Synon. concernant, eu égard à, quant à, au sujet de

Lorsque tu atteins ou dépasses le seuil de 40 heures de travail cumulé relativement à tes deux fonctions dans la compagnie, est-ce que ton taux de rémunération est majoré? Les heures en ce qui concerne chaque fonction sont-elles combinées ou sont-elles traitées séparément?